# iOS- Apple push notification resend from APNS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

From Apple's document I understand that if the device is offline, the APNS holds the last  notification and sends it to the device when the device is back online. Is there is any mechanism to avoid that resending?

Comment: NO once you have send request to APNS you can do nothing.

Comment: What do u mean by user specific?

Comment: my problem is that my app is used different users from same device. i can handle it online but my app has offline logout fissility.so  if one user is logout offline then the device is online. is it possible  reached already sended push notifications to  my device?

Comment: You should reconisder which answer should be accepted for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **NO**

Here is what apple says about it,

> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored.
>   If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each
>   new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded.

Comment: Hi Prem Kumar thank you for the quick response. i would like to know whether i will get the push notification when my intended user is logged out but my device is online. also is there any way to restrict those messages in such a scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by user is logged out? Do you mean user has disabled push notification for your application?

Answer (score 17):

The correct answer is **YES**

If you send notifications using the [enhanced binary format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4) (the one that includes message identifier and expiry), you can use the expiry parameter to prevent the notification from being stored in the APN server. This way the notification is delivered only if the device is online when the APN server first tries to deliver it.

> **Expiry**
>
> A fixed UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC) that identifies when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded. The expiry value uses network byte order (big endian). If the expiry value is positive, APNs tries to deliver the notification at least once. **Specify zero (or a value less than zero) to request that APNs not store the notification at all**.

Comment: Updating that Apple release a new endpoint implemented in HTTP/2. You can still supply Expiry as an HTTP header for the request.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Eran.

This part of your question "the APNS holds the last notification and sends it to the device when the device is back online" is only true if Expiration date is different of zero.

If you do want the message to be delivered when the phone gets online, the message will wait until "Expiration date" before be discarded.

APNS documentation:

> Expiration date 4 bytes A UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC)
>   that identifies when the notification is no longer valid and can be
>   discarded. **If this value is non-zero, APNs stores the notification
>   tries to deliver the notification at least once. Specify zero to
>   indicate that the notification expires immediately and that APNs
>   should not store the notification at all**.

For more details, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Comment: Updated documentation link here. Look for description of apns-expiration:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns