# APNS notification not received when device offline

Tags: azure

When using Azure Notification hub , the notification is getting lost if
the device is offline. How do I ensure the notification is re sent when
the device is back online?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Notification Hub (NH) sends notifications to iOS devices thru the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) which means that NH does not communicate with device directly and obviously it does not track if device is online. APNS takes care about device, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741037/2379216).